# How to add dimensions to Google analytics api requets

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

The examples given by Google are a very simple query request. however, when I try to add more parameters, it will throw errors and I don't exactly know how to structure the syntax.

This simple query request works:

```
 return $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $viewID,
  $startDate,
  $endDate,
  'ga:sessions'
);
```

I need more information and I've already used [Google's Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to get the Information but I just don't know how to structure my PHP query. The Information I want to request is also ga:pageviews as another metric, ga:pagePath and ga:pageTitle as dimensions and also a filter. I already fail at adding a second metric.

I have tried this:

```
return $analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $viewID,
  $startDate,
  $endDate,
  'ga:sessions',
  'ga:pageviews'
);
```

simply adding it doesn't work. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimensions need to be added as option parms

```
//Adding Dimensions 
$params = array('dimensions' => 'ga:userType'); 
// requesting the data  
$data = $service->data_ga->get("ga:89798036", "2014-12-14", "2014-12-14", "ga:users,ga:sessions", $params );
```

Comment: I logged a bug to the team see if we cant get an example up with using dimensions it was an oversight I am sure.